# React production build not showing page after logging in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React returns an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` error and I was able to figure out that it's because the script tag returns HTML instead of Javascript bundle. This only happens when trying to navigate programmatically, say after logging in. Other pages show fine but.

How do I make the script tag return Javascript instead of HTML? Also, why does the script tag return HTML instead of JavaScript when the program navigates programmatically.

I'm using the React-router package to route the pages and I'm suspecting it has something to do with it. If so, any way around it?

**App.js**

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";

import LandingPage from "./LandingPage";

import Login from "./authentication/Login";
import RequireAuth from "./authentication/RequireAuth";
import Register from "./authentication/Register";

import ClientDashboard from "./dashboard/client/ClientDashboard";
import LoanRequest from "./dashboard/client/LoanRequest";
import Offers from "./dashboard/client/Offers";

import ShowOffer from "./dashboard/client/ShowOffer";
import EditOffer from "./dashboard/client/EditOffer";
import PublishOffer from "./dashboard/client/PublishOffer";

import InvestorDashboard from "./dashboard/investor/InvestorDashboard";
import InvestorDashboard2 from "./dashboard/investor/InvestorDashboard2";
import InvestorOffers from "./dashboard/investor/InvestorOffers";
import InvestorBids from "./dashboard/investor/InvestorBids";
import InvestorDeclinedBids from "./dashboard/investor/InvestorDeclinedBids";

import Profile from "./dashboard/client/ProfileSettings";

import BrokerDashboard from "./dashboard/broker/Dashboard";
import NewClient from "./dashboard/broker/NewClient";
import AllClients from "./dashboard/broker/AllClients";
import NewOffer from "./dashboard/broker/NewOffer";
import NewOfferTranche from "./dashboard/broker/NewOfferTranche";
import NewOfferTiming from "./dashboard/broker/NewOfferTiming";

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />

        {/*Client dashboard*/}
        <Route
          path="/client/dashboard"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <ClientDashboard />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/client/new-loan"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <LoanRequest />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/client/offers"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <Offers />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/client/offers/offer"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <ShowOffer />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/client/offers/offer/edit"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <EditOffer />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/client/offers/offer/publish"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <PublishOffer />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />

        {/*Investor Dashboard*/}
        <Route
          path="/investor/dashboard"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <InvestorDashboard />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/investor/offers"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <InvestorDashboard2 />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/investor/offers/offer"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <InvestorOffers />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/investor/bids"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <InvestorBids />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/investor/bids/declined"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <InvestorDeclinedBids />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate, useLocation, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { signInAsync } from "../../redux/authSlice";

import DocumentHead from "../DocumentHead";
import Button from "../Button";

import setBgImage from "../../utils/setBgImage";
import phoneLady from "../../assets/images/phoneLady.jpg";

export default function Login() {
    const pageName = "Login";
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { state } = useLocation();

    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        emailAddress: "",
        password: "",
        isChecked: false,
        isLoading: false,
    });


    const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({
        emailAddress: "",
        password: "",
        emptyFields: "",
    });

    const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

    const { message } = useSelector((state) => state.message.server);

    // Dipstach Redux actions
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const target = e.target;
        const name = target.name;
        const value =
            target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;

        setForm((state) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                [name]: value,
            };
        });
    };

    // Input from form state
    const { emailAddress, password } = form;

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setForm((state) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
            };
        });

        const data = { email: emailAddress, password };

        for (let props in data) {
            if (data[props] === "" || data[props] === null) {
                setForm((state) => ({...state, isLoading: false}));
                setFormErrors((state) => ({...state, emptyFields: "Please fill in the fields"}));
                return
            } 
        }

        // Redux hook dispatches sign-in action (Login requst)
        dispatch(signInAsync(data)).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);

            if ("user" in response) {

                const userType = response.user.groups[0];

                if (userType.name === "Client") {
                    navigate(state?.path || "/client/dashboard"); // <----- Error upon navigation

                    // Reload to update Redux state
                    window.location.reload()
                }

                if (userType.name === "Broker") {
                    navigate(state?.path || "/broker/dashboard"); // <----- Error upon navigation

                    // Reload to update Redux state
                    window.location.reload()
                }

                if (userType.name === "Investor") {
                    navigate(state?.path || "/investor/dashboard"); // <--- Error upon navigation

                    // Reload to update Redux state
                    window.location.reload()
                }

                return
            }
        });
    };

    if (isLoggedIn) return (<Navigate to="/" replace />);

    return (
        <>
            <DocumentHead title={pageName} />
            <section id="orderbook-login" className="orderbook-authentication">
                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 h-full">
                    <div
                        id="intro-background"
                        className="hidden md:block"
                        style={setBgImage && setBgImage(phoneLady)}
                    >
                        <div
                            id="login-intro"
                            className="flex flex-col items-center auth-intro"
                        >
                            <div
                                id="login-title"
                                className="bg-white px-6 mb-3 self-start flex items-center justify-center shadow-md orderbook-icon"
                            >
                                Orderbook
                            </div>
                            <h1 className="shadow-sm">
                                Welcome to your go to financial platform
                            </h1>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
                                enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="overlay"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="orderbook-form">
                        <form
                            className="h-full"
                            onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
                        >
                            <div className="pt-20 pb-10 px-12">
                                <h1
                                    id="orderbook-home"
                                    className="text-center mb-10 leading-6 md:hidden"
                                >
                                    <Link to="/" className="text-gray-400">
                                        Orderbook Online
                                    </Link>
                                </h1>
                                <div className="px-4 sm:px-0 mb-3">
                                    <h2 className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 pb-3 sm:pb-2">
                                        Welcome back
                                    </h2>
                                    <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
                                        Log into your account
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-5">
                                    <div className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="emailAddress"
                                            id="email-address"
                                            autoComplete="email"
                                            placeholder="Email"
                                            className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                            required
                                            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                                        <input
                                            type="password"
                                            name="password"
                                            id="password"
                                            autoComplete="password"
                                            placeholder="Password"
                                            className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                            required
                                            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                                        <div className="flex items-start">
                                            <div className="flex items-center h-5">
                                                <input
                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                    name="isChecked"
                                                    id="persist-login"
                                                    className="focus:ring-white h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-black rounded"
                                                    onChange={(e) =>
                                                        handleChange(e)
                                                    }
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="ml-3 text-sm">
                                                <label
                                                    htmlFor="persist-login"
                                                    className="font-medium text-black"
                                                >
                                                    Keep me logged in
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4 mt-1 flex items-end">
                                        <Link
                                            to="#"
                                            id="forgot-password"
                                            className="w-full"
                                        >
                                            Forgot password?
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4 mt-1">
                                        <Button
                                            type="submit"
                                            buttonClass="login-button auth-button"
                                        >
                                            Login{" "}
                                            {form.isLoading ? (
                                                <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw" style={{fontSize: 20}}></i>
                                            ) : null}
                                        </Button>
                                    </div>

                                    <div
                                        id="dont-have-account"
                                        className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4 mt-1 text-center account-signal"
                                    >
                                        <span>Don't have an account yet?</span>{" "}
                                        <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: you should not be using `window.location.reload()` to reload/update your redux state (or really do anything). You should only update/modify redux state by dispatching actions.

Comment: If your script tag is returning HTML, this indicates that reloading the page any time you're on a page that isn't the root will have a similar issue due to the webserver not resolving the relative url used in the script tag at that url path. The script tags should probably be using an absolute path instead. Avoiding window.location.reload will surely stop the error you're having now, but it won't stop the error from when the user presses F5.

Comment: @WillEvers I only did so because the dispatch don't update the state. The dispatch happens outside of the component. Could that be why?

Comment: If the dispatch is not updating the redux state then you must have an issue with your redux reducer.

Comment: @KevinB I removed the reload code and the same problem persist. I still can't figure out why the script doesn't load JavaScript on that URL path. It works in the development server but when I server the react build directory to simulate production, it spits the same error.

Comment: @WillEvers I only used it since the dispatch was updating the redux store. I look into that in the future. The current disturbing issue is the React build not serving the script after I log in. Everything works fine locally but not when I serve the production build. I'm yet to find a solution!

Comment: - what is the html that your script tag is trying to get?

- what is the src="..." on the script tag in the case when it errors?

It seems to me that when you use navigat with react router the script tag somehow tries to fetch the script from an invalid path

Comment: @KevinB Hmmm! But I can reload (manual reload) other pages served by react-router in production and they work fine. However, it makes sense because the issue occurs after the page programmatically navigates, say from '/login' to `/dashboard` and then it reloads programmatically. The only reason I have `window.location.reload()` is because the dispatch doesn't update the redux store. I will test this from the ground up and get back. I'll appreciate it if you can follow up.

Comment: @Romeo think about what happens when you reload. What path is being sent to your server for not only the html, but the script tags in your html. (This is a rhetorical question)

Comment: If your script tag is pointing to `src="myscripts.js"` and you're on `example.com/myapp`, the browser looks for the script tag at `example.com/myapp/myscript.js`. If you change to another route in react, your address bar updates to `example.com/myapp/someroute`... now when you reload, that will be the address the server is serving, so the browser will try to request the script tag from `example.com/myapp/someroute/myscript.js`, which will 404. Your build process should be outputting absolute urls for script tags, or you should be setting the root to `/`.

Comment: This isn't a problem with your app code/react router or noscript, its just your index.html/build process. You haven't provided your build process, so i can't provide the duplicate.

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproductible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @KevinB Your suggestion made me think and rewrite the auth logic in redux asynchronously and the navigation logic in the `Login` component. The reload meant to update the Redux store is  anti-pattern and it messed with the URL path in the `<script>` tag as you said.

Comment: that might solve your near-term problem, but it's still gonna break if anyone decides to press F5 for whatever reason after navigating away from root (or creates a bookmark at not root)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `window.location.reload()` to update your state, the `dispatch` should modify the state for you.

What I think is happening is that your state is getting updated but your UI isn't responding to that change, your UI should react to the state update instead of you manually having to reload your UI.